# How can I format a variable containing time from a database using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, variables, time, format

I have a variable which displays the time. This gets retrieved from a database. The issue is, it gets displayed like this: 22:30:00. Is there a way to format this variable before it gets displayed? My variable name is $time. It should be like this: 22:30

```
$query = "SELECT time FROM tasks";
$stm = $con->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo "<table>";
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    $time = $pers->time;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$time."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";


}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: if youre going to downvote, atleast explain why

Comment: `substr` function.

Comment: Please provide a code by which you are getting time from the Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$time = date('H:i', strtotime( $time ) );
```

@Marce provided this code as well, but it `date()` function requires timestamp as the second parameter which can be done by strtotime.

1. date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
2. strtotime: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Please refer the documentation for further assistance.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
date("H:i", strtotime($time));
```

Comment: i get this error: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: @MAN8zzzzzzzzzDWOMAN It may works if $time is a timestamp rather than the time as you provided in your question.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @MAN8zzzzzzzzzDWOMAN By the way, how you are fetching time from the DataBase?

Comment: @MAN8zzzzzzzzzDWOMAN Please check my answer as provided above.

Comment: @Marce Your solution almost right just missing the timestamp as the second parameter. Please refer the `date()` documentation for more clarification: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui I edited the answer 15 minutes ago

Comment: @Marce Great (Y)